# Does CakePHP v1.3.8 have a $this->redirect header injection?

Tags: php, security, cakephp, header-injection

I wrote the following code in a controller:

```php
$this->redirect('https://example.com' . $this->here);
```

Does it have a header injection?

```
ex) http://example.com/%0dSet-Cookie:XXXX=YYYYY
```

Please tell me how to fix.

Comment: what are you trying to acheive? What is $this->here?

Comment: In this particular case, `$this->here` is the current URL, therefore it won't be possible to "inject" anything here.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in CakePHP is directly vulnerable, but neither does it code defensively against it. To perform the actual redirect `Controller->redirect()` calls `Controller->header()`, which in turn calls [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). So it is the version of PHP that is in use that will dictate whether you are vulnerable to HTTP header injection  or not. This vulnerability was [remediated in `header()` in releases 4.4.2 and 5.1.2 of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-changelog).

However, you should never be putting untrusted or unknown content in the location header, so code defensively with whitelist validation and you'll be fine.